# IceFaces 3.3.0 ace:pushbutton with image. How to do it?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, icefaces-3

I've been struggling trying to add an image to an IceFaces pushButton.

My last try was adding an image nested to pushbutton tags like this:

```
<ace:pushButton actionListener="#{logoutCtrl.logout()}">
        <h:graphicImage value="img/logout.png" width="20px" height="20px"/>
</ace:pushButton>
```

But unfortunately it didn't work. The page shows the button with no label and than the image, like:

[image: Doesn't work!!!]

I've found [this link](http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-7016) where they mentioned that it should be fixed since version 2.x, so I am probably doing something wrong.

P.S - I would normally use Prime Faces but I don't have a choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with ICEFaces 4. In my case, the image would display next to the button. I guess, I could have styled the button in CSS. Instead I just replaced the *ace:pushButton* element with standard JSF *h:commandButton* component. The *h:commandButton* has an image attribute. Here is an example:

`<h:commandButton image="#{resource['images:searchIcon.png']}" 
  action="#{myBean.performSearch}">
    <f:param name="callback" value="sessionSearch"/>
</h:commandButton>`

Hopefully this can help someone.

Comment: `<h:commandButton image>` serves a different purpose in HTML (image map to get X,Y coordinates of mouse pointer). Just use `<h:commandLink><h:graphicImage>`.

Comment: @BalusC, I was not aware of this. I guess since action is a redirect, your solution should be more elegant. I went with JSF documentation which states: [Absolute or relative URL of the image to be displayed for this button.(under image attribute h:commandButton component description)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-jsp/toc.htm)